# How to validate a form with multiple models?

Tags: php, laravel, validation

Basically, I am building an online shop where the user can create products with options (so, let's say, a size and a color). When all the options are set, they must provide a quantity and the SKU of each product.

I was thinking of making a two step form.

1st step: they select the name, description, images and create the options (size[sm, m, l, xl] and color[blue, red, yellow]). On the page after, I generated a list of forms for each option (small yellow jacket, small blue jacket, small white jacket, medium yellow jacket, medium blue jacket, medium white jacket, etc.)

Basically, a lot of lines of form that I have to validate. However, I don't see how I can get the data and validate it.

The generated names will each have an associated id and that id needs to be in the form. I was thinking of putting it in the names (sku-1, quantity-1, but this wouldn't work for validation). Thought about making an array but how would I know which value belongs to which product?

How do you handle form validation/matching when you have a lot of models to work with like in my case?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to [manually create a validator](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#manually-creating-validators)

Basic validation looks like this (from the docs linked above):

```php
Validator::make($request->all(), [
    'title' => 'required|unique:posts|max:255',
    'body' => 'required',
])->validate();
```

If your validation is more complex than static checks on certain attributes, you'll need to write something a bit more complex to match.

Comment: This doesn't really answer my question. I know how to do that. Let's say you have a list of 10 models which you can edit in your page. 10 forms combined in one, when you submit, you must check the data for each model. You can't make individual submit. How do you handle that?